# Extracting a string after pattern PostgreSQL

Tags: regex, string, postgresql, substring

So I have a column like the following:

```
diagnosis

715.16 oSTEOARTHRITIS, LOWER-LEG 
715.17 - OSTEOARTHRITIS, ANKLE AND FOOT
715.90 oSTEOARTHRITIS, UNSPECIFIED
716.10 - TRAUMATIC ARTHROPATHY - UNSPECIFIED
```

Some entries have initial dashes, some do not. Some have dashes later in the string.

I'd like to select the *substring (in itallics)* with the pattern:

(any chars)(dash)(space)*(any alphanumeric)(the rest of the string)*

OR

(any chars)(space)*(any alphanumeric)(the rest of the string)*

My query goes:
`select substring(diagnosis from '% #"\w%#"' for '#') from TableICDdict;`

but it just returns all the rows with empty strings in them (no errors). Any ideas on how to actually output the extracted substrings?

Thanks

Comment: Here's the documentation on regular expressions, but they don't use the substring function in context at all. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html

Comment: If I enter 'A' for the '\w', I get some substrings starting with the letter 'A', and those rows that don't match are NULL. I guess I just need to replace '\w' with the correct wildcard for "any alphanumeric."

Answer (score 2):

Use `regexp_replace()` to skip all characters preceding first space (and the space) and `ltrim()` to skip additional '- ' strings:

```
with t(diagnosis) as (values 
    ('715.16 oSTEOARTHRITIS, LOWER-LEG'),
    ('715.17 - OSTEOARTHRITIS, ANKLE AND FOOT'),
    ('715.90 oSTEOARTHRITIS, UNSPECIFIED'),
    ('716.10 - TRAUMATIC ARTHROPATHY - UNSPECIFIED'))
select ltrim(regexp_replace(diagnosis, '.*? (.*)', '\1'), '- ') result
from t;

               result                
-------------------------------------
 oSTEOARTHRITIS, LOWER-LEG
 OSTEOARTHRITIS, ANKLE AND FOOT
 oSTEOARTHRITIS, UNSPECIFIED
 TRAUMATIC ARTHROPATHY - UNSPECIFIED
(4 rows)
```